# Merge two select statements from same table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a query which merges the results of two queries from the same table.

```
select
(select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr1 from  dbo.Cases)
(select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr2 from dbo.Cases where Case_Status = 'Open')
```

The above produces two sets of results, what i want is a single set of results with `expr1` &
`expr2` as two separate columns. I will later use this result in SRSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
     count(*) as expr1, 
     sum(case when Case_Status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end)
from dbo.Cases
```

Comment: Got this error:Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: Sorry, just missing a bracket sum(distinct(case when Case_Status = 'Open' then 1 else 0 end))

Comment: yes, just editted it though to make it simpler. The distinct in that case is not necessary (assuming Case_ID is your primary key)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are preety close. This should work

```
select
  (select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr1 from  dbo.Cases)
, (select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr2 from dbo.Cases where Case_Status = 'Open'
```

May just be missing the comma between the two fields?

Comment: select
  (select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr1 from  dbo.Cases)
, (select count(distinct(Case_ID)) as expr2 from dbo.Cases where Case_Status = 'Open')

Comment: Works just need a extra bracket at the end. However i have no column names unfortunately?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to count distinct cases:

```
select count(distinct case_id) as NumCases, 
       count(case when Case_Status = 'Open' then case_id end) as NumOpen
from dbo.Cases;
```

Note:  if `Case_Id` is unique in `Cases`, then the `distinct` is not necessary.  However, you have it in the original query, suggesting this may not be the case.  The `distinct` performs worse than a regular `count()` or `sum()`.